# Modelling query in regression

Tags: classification, regression, feature-selection, linear-regression, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to build a regression model, where I see which attributes are influencing the margin. My data set looks like something below.

```
UserId  |  [products_bought] | revenue |  [places_visited] | discount  --> Margin
```

In the above mentioned schema a single user might have bought a set of products maximum of 4000 and places visited can be in hundreds.

I tried to flatten the data but this is very sparse, are there any approaches to efficiently model this kind of problem

Comment: Do you have revenue per product, or just total revenue for each customer?

Comment: @Paul I've total revenue per customer not at product level